# Change properties of tkinter frame, from outside the frame

Tags: python, tkinter

How does one act on a tkinter widget that's created outside the current function? The `print` statement below shows the frame names exist, but how do I get to them?

The goal is to change attributes like background and foreground colours when the buttons are pushed. Only button one shown in the example below. There also multiple frames at play in the real application.

```
from tkinter import *
ALL=N+S+W+E

class Application(Frame):
    def create_buttons(self):
        self.b = Button(self, text='Green',
            command=lambda: self.set_text_color('Green'))
        self.b.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=ALL)
        #...

    def set_text_color(self, color):
        print("Setting text color", self, color)
        ## none of these work as frame_1 doesn't exist here
        ## how to act on a frame up the tree?
        #self.frame_1.config({'bg':color})
        #top.frame_1.config({'bg':color})
        #app.top.frame_1.config({'bg':color})
        #app.f1.config({'bg':color})
        f1.config({'bg':color})

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, padx=10, pady=10, name='top')
        self.config({'bg':'bisque'})
        self.rowconfigure(0, minsize=50, weight=1)
        self.grid(sticky=ALL)

        f1 = Frame(self, padx=10, pady=10, name='frame_1')
        f1.config({'bg':'cornsilk'})
        f1.rowconfigure(0, minsize=20, weight=1)
        f1.grid(sticky=ALL, columnspan=2)

        #...

        self.create_buttons()

root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Result of clicking on the [Green] button:

```
Setting text color .top Green
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1456, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "B:\py2\09\xx-set-color.py", line 7, in <lambda>
    command=lambda: self.set_text_color('Green'))
  File "B:\py2\09\xx-set-color.py", line 19, in set_text_color
    f1.config({'bg':color})
NameError: global name 'f1' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is save a reference to f1 when you create it:

```
def __init__(self, master=None):
    ...
    self.f1 = Frame(...)
    ...
```

Once you do that, you refer to it as `self.f1` within the class. .

Comment: argh! (Yay!, but *argh!*) I fought with this for **hours.** Thank you so much.